# How to edit cell value in VB.net - Using .Interop.Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, com, interop, cell

This is a simple question. I have this code:

```
 CurrentRow = 3
 MyColumn = 2
 CurrentCell = (CurrentRow & "," & MyColumn)
 WorkingSheet.Cells(CurrentCell).value = (ClientName & " " & "(" & ClientLocation & ")" & " " & ExtraDefinition)
```

I thought that this would place the data on the 'WorkingSheet' in the position "B3" but it places the data in the cell "AF1".

Why is this?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cell` is not expected to be used as you are using it; you have to input the row and column indices (as integers) separated by a comma. Thus the right code is:

```
WorkingSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, MyColumn).Value = (ClientName & " " & "(" & ClientLocation & ")" & " " & ExtraDefinition)
```

Another alternative you have is using `Range`. Example:

```
WorkingSheet.Range("B3").Value = (ClientName & " " & "(" & ClientLocation & ")" & " " & ExtraDefinition)
```

Comment: For some reason the .Range function, which I had originally used in VBA, throws me _HRESULT 0x800A03EC_ in VB.net so I'm trying to avoid it... **But thank-you for you help! It works properly now!**

Comment: @Josh "Range" should work fine too. You have to check the exact conditions under which you are using it.